# Template overload issues with pointers and ints in 64 bit

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I am having an issue with my templates and overloads mismatching pointers as ints.

> C:/Users/Bakaiya/Desktop/Onathe/src/AdminPlanetRepresentation.cpp:24:66: error: cast from 'AdminPlanet*' to 'int' loses precision [-fpermissive]
>   U::log( U::c( " + Creating planet representation ", int( target ) ) );

I have several overloads to the "c()" template, but my current issue revolves around why the one I recently added, the pointer overload, is not solving this problem.

```
template<class T>
inline String c( T a )
{
    return Ogre::StringConverter::toString( a );
}

template<class T>
inline String c( T* a )
{
    return c( (uint64_t)a );
}
```

And the multi-parameter templates:

```
template<class T, typename... Args>
inline String c( T a, Args... args );
template<class T, typename... Args>
inline String c( T* a, Args... args );

...

template<class T, typename... Args>
inline String c( T a, Args... args )
{
    return Ogre::StringConverter::toString( a ) + c( args... );
}

template<class T, typename... Args>
inline String c( T* a, Args... args )
{
    return c( a ) + c( args... );
}
```

Previously I was building as 32 bit, and there was no issue letting pointers be implicitly cast to the general template, `c( T a )`. On 64 bit builds, though, that's not enough.

Why is the overload not catching pointers and preventing them from being implicitly cast to int?

The full file with the other overloads and templates is [available here.](https://github.com/WilliamKappler/onathacar/blob/master/inc/Utility.h)

Comment: Does it work better using `T const* a` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Corrected terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to linked code, problem is `int( target )` in `U::log( U::c( " + Creating planet representation ", int( target ) ) );` and is unrelated to code shown here.

Use `uintptr_t(target)` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're right. Unfortunately because I spent an hour trying to figure this out and somehow kept missing the fact I was messing up the call itself. Well, that solves it. The templates work fine when called properly!